# Labeling values using fct_collapse and running regressions for only a group within a data frame list

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, regression, forcats

I'm trying to do multiple things with a list. For reproducible example, I'll use Iris.
lets say, for the example, that i have a list of multiple iris datasets. In my case, the values differ. For this example, using iris*2 doesnt work, as species returns NA when you multiply. Assume they are different.
`Iris1 <- iris Iris2 <- iris Iris3 <- iris data_list <- list(Iris1, Iris2, Iris3)`
then i'm trying to run an fct_collapse with dplyr to the data list with lapply, with no success. Individually, it'd be like
`Iris1 <- Iris1%>% group_by(Sepal.Length = fct_collapse(as.character(Sepal.Length), Group1 = as.character(5:7), Group2 = as.character(3:5)))`
After running it to data_list, i'd like to run a lm() to data_list, filtering based on Group. so , run a lm(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length) for only Group1, in all the dataframes within data_list.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand well the probleme, please find here a proposal solution using a nested data.frame. This will let you create a lm per group and dataset an elagant way.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

Iris1 <- Iris2 <-  Iris3 <- 
  iris %>%
  ## trick to make sepal length an integer to be in the same shape than the user
  ## create a regional variable UF
  mutate(
    UF = sample(1:10, n(), replace = TRUE)
  )

## merge the dataset
data_merged <- 
  ## merge the dataset adding a dataset id that identify the dataset  
  bind_rows(
    Iris1 %>% add_column(data.set.id = 1), 
    Iris2 %>% add_column(data.set.id = 2), 
    Iris3 %>% add_column(data.set.id = 3)
  ) %>%
  ## create the regional aggreagation variable
  mutate(
    region.agg = 
      fct_collapse(
        factor(UF), 
        group1 = paste(1:3), 
        group2 = paste(4:7), 
        group3 = paste(8:10))
  )

## now we have a correctly formated data.frame you can apply a lm() per data.set
## and region. Here the model will be lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width)
data_mod <-
  data_merged %>%
  nest(data = - any_of(c('data.set.id', 'region.agg'))) %>%
  mutate(
    mod  = map(data, ~ lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .x))
  )

## you have now a single lm per data.frame and regional group combination
data_mod

## you can print them all 
data_mod$mod

## or access just one of interest (e.g. 2nd data.set group2)
data_mod %>%
  filter(data.set.id == 2, region.agg == 'group2') %>%
  pull('mod') %>%
  magrittr::extract2(1)
```

Which should give:

```
> data_mod
# A tibble: 9 × 4
  data.set.id region.agg data              mod   
        <dbl> <fct>      <list>            <list>
1           1 group3     <tibble [40 × 6]> <lm>  
2           1 group1     <tibble [46 × 6]> <lm>  
3           1 group2     <tibble [64 × 6]> <lm>  
4           2 group3     <tibble [40 × 6]> <lm>  
5           2 group1     <tibble [46 × 6]> <lm>  
6           2 group2     <tibble [64 × 6]> <lm>  
7           3 group3     <tibble [40 × 6]> <lm>  
8           3 group1     <tibble [46 × 6]> <lm>  
9           3 group2     <tibble [64 × 6]> <lm>  

> ## you can print them all 
> data_mod$mod
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
     7.2212      -0.3695  


.....

[[9]]

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
     6.3680      -0.1712  



> ## or access just one of interest (e.g. 2nd data.set group2)
> data_mod %>%
+   filter(data.set.id == 2, region.agg == 'group2') %>%
+   pull('mod') %>%
+   magrittr::extract2(1)

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
     6.3680      -0.1712
```